# JSON transmission from the controller to the view in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, json

Sorry for my bad English. I have a problem. When I pass JSON data from view, I get an error: "Illegal characters in path."
That my controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private WeaponContext _db = new WeaponContext();
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var allWeapons = _db.Weapons.ToList<Weapon>();
        var allWeaponsJSON = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(allWeapons);
        return View(allWeaponsJSON);
    }
}
```

and that my index.html:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
@using TestingApp.Models
@model IEnumerable<Weapon>
    <h3>Weapons</h3>
        <table class="center">
        <tr><td><p><h3>Name of weapon</h3></p></td><td><p><h3>Created</h3></p></td><td><p><h3>Description</h3></p></td></tr>
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: model.Weapon"></tbody>
             <tr><td><span data-bind="text: Title"></span></td><td><span data-bind="text: Created"></span></td><td><span data-bind="text: Description"></span></td></tr>

        </table>
<script type="text/javascript" src='@Url.Content("~/Scripts/knockout-2.3.0.js")'>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var viewWeapons = {};
        $.getJSON("/index", function (data) {
            viewWeapons = ko.mapping.fromJSON(data);

        });
    });
    ko.applyBindings(viewWeapons);
</script>
@section Footer {
    Все права защищены. Vlad Corp. 2013.
}
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return `JsonResult`

```
public JsonResult Index()
{
    var allWeapons = _db.Weapons.ToList<Weapon>();
    return Json(allWeapons, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet );
}
```

You need to set `, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet`, if you want allow 'GET'

Comment: public JsonResult Index()
{
    var allWeapons = _db.Weapons.ToList<Weapon>();
    return Json(allWeapons, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet );
}

When i correct this, it's working